# edit Joomla 3.x library file (to customize form validation error messages)

Tags: validation, joomla, overriding

I want to change some lines in this Joomla's (3.6.5) library file:

> C:\xampp\htdocs\joomla\libraries\joomla\form\form.php

I searched many places to find out how to do this, but unfortunately there isn't a clear answer that explains step by step how can I override this library file in my template. The only thing I've found is that it's possible to override library files, but it has its downsides (security threats after upgrades).
By editing this library file my purpose is change the messages shown after form validation errors. Joomla only shows "invalid field: field label", but I want to change it and force it to clearly explains what is wrong about the field for user can understand which he/she input wrong.
After solving the above problem, I want to know how can I show each field's error message below it's input box, I don't like Joomla's default way that shows all the errors in a div above the form.
Please help me. There's no website I haven't searched it for this problem to solve.

Comment: You probably are better off asking at [joomla.se] which is the SE site for joomla.

Comment: Also I don't believe that what you want has anything to do with the library file, the library just returns the error array, it does not do anything about how that is rendered. That is not the job of a library.

Comment: first part of my question (changing the error message text) relates to library files

Comment: No it does not. Do you see any translatable text in that file? No. If anything it is in the rule file.  What you could do is write a custom rule which you would store in your custom libraries.  Also you are really asking two separate questions.